# Нет передачи данных в БД

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, база-данных

Не вижу в чем может быть загвоздка.Сделал форму,подключил Ajax , после запись в БД. Но дело в том,что все работает вроде как корректно,ошибок никаких не выдает и в браузере тоже.Но запись из формы не передается в БД

```
//Сама форма

<div class="form-control"  style="min-height: 100px;"><p><br></p></div>
<p><form  action=  method="post"></p>
<input type="text" id="soob" class="form-control">
<p><button id="mes_send" type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-5">
    Отправить
</button></p>
</form>


//Ajax

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$('#mes_send').click(function () {
var soob = $ ('#soob').val();


$.ajax({

  url:'reg/chat.php',
  type : 'POST',
  data : {'soob' : soob},

success: function (data) {

  $("#soob").val('');

}

});
});

</script>


//PHP


<?


if(isset($_POST['soob'])){

require_once '../mysql.php';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `chat`(`soob`) VALUES(?)";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute([$soob]);
   }

?>
```

Comment: как вариант url:'reg/chat.php' неправильный адрес, скрипт заключен в блок  jquery ready? есть проверка наличия $_POST['soob'], а в скл-запрос вставляешь $soob

Comment: Смотрите в отладчике браузера (вкладка Сеть) - отправляется верный запрос, или нет, что отправляется, какой код приходит - 200, или иной.  Неплохо-бы до записи в БД вывести отладочную инфу - выведите свой ```$_POST['soob']```

Comment: Проблему решил,действительно как говорил один из надеюсь будущих коллег :"есть проверка наличия $_POST['soob'], а в скл-запрос вставляешь $soob" Я в этой строке $query->execute([$soob]);  исправил что я передаю в массив.НЕ переменную нужно было передавать,так как действительно откуда ее взять,а вот так $query->execute(['soob']);Всем спасибо